# Recyclerview : how to load only currently displayed items?

Tags: java, android, xml, optimization, android-recyclerview

I have an app with a `MainActivity`, which launch a `SecondActivity` where I have a `recyclerView` with lots of items, and each item contains an image. When calling the `startActivity()` method to launch the `SecondActivity`, I observe some delay because all items are loaded before the secondActivity start.

I'm trying to load only items that are displayed on screen, and load the rest of them only when the user scrolls, **step by step**, so there is no latency anymore when calling the `SecondActivity`.

Here is my code :

**mainActivity.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/mainLayoutBackground"
    tools:context=".main.MainActivity">

    <!-- some stuff --> 

     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**recyclerview_item.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/mainLayoutBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/first_card_view_halo"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/blue"
        app:cardCornerRadius="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/second_card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="150dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/img" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I set the images of each items programmatically with `adapter` and `viewHolder`, and I observe a few seconds latency when launching `SecondActivity`.

How to load only currently displayed items ?

Comment: Do you use a pagging like https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview

Comment: @Alexander would you have an example using Java ? The only docs / examples I managed to find are in Kotlin

Comment: Yes, it's the current language for android development. I am not sure I can find a good sample on Java, now